# how to perform a segue in AppDelegate.swift using swift

Tags: ios, swift, segue, appdelegate, swift5

I am making an IOS app and am trying to perform a segue in the AppDelegate after using Google Sign In to sign the user in my app. I have looked at many other questions like this in stack overflow, but I couldn't find anything that works. Everything is too out dated.

I just need one line that performs a segue. Below is my code leading up to this point and where I want the segue to be is where I have a comment saying "What to do after you are signed in".

```
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        guard let authentication = user.authentication else { return }
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: authentication.idToken, accessToken: authentication.accessToken)
        
    
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            if let error = error {
                let authError = error as NSError
                return
            }
        }
            
        //What to do after you are signed in
```

}

Can someone just let me know the line of code I need to perform a segue from the AppDelegate.swift file.

Comment: You can't (directly). And it's not just a line of code. You could use a callback closure from the affected view controller, protocol/delegate or Notification. Or you could set the GID delegate to the affected view controller and implement the delegate method there.

Comment: I am ok not using a line of code to perform the segue. Can you show me what I have to do?

Comment: It's not enough information in your question to provide a concrete suggestion. Please [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+perform+segue+appdelegate). There are a lot of related questions.

Comment: I have searched a lot of other posts and tried a lot of other solutions, but none of them worked. What other information do you need to help me with this question?

Comment: There's not a universal answer for this because it depends how your view controller hierarchy is built.

Comment: So, what do you need? Should I take a screenshot of my hierarchy and show it to you, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

I found this helpful https://fluffy.es/how-to-transition-from-login-screen-to-tab-bar-controller/

The problem is that from iOS 13, AppDelegate no longer handles the job of transitioning between views, it's been replaced by SceneDelegate. The how-to shows how to get around this by changing the rootViewController instead.